# Need more information about samanera or sramanera in India(Theravada tradition)?

Tags: theravada, monk, ordination

I am planning to be samanera or sramanera for now. Later, would like to be a buddhist monk. I am interested in Theravada tradition. I live in India. But I have no idea what is the procedure to be one or to whom to contact for that. Is there anyone who can guide me on this?

Comment: Which tradition are you interested in? Theravada, Mahayana, Tibetan, Zen etc.?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I am interested in Theravada tradition. I'll include this in my question, so it'll be helpful for others to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Maha Bodhi Society](http://www.mahabodhi.info/about.html) in India. They have monastic training centers in Bengaluru and Hyderabad.

There's another monastery called the [Mahabodhi Jetavana Monastery](http://www.mahabodhi-ladakh.org/monastery.html) in Ladakh.

I found these through Google, to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

Tony Montana, sadhu for you intention. Most general in regard of ordination can be found in the [Mahavaga](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/vin/mv/index_en.html#mv01).

Aside of certain contitions (deptless, agreement of parents...) one does good to find a good and relayable preceptor of which is the most difficult, and as far heard specially not easy to find in India where the Sangha has not the best reputations in regard of Vinaya.

The procedure is certain simple, having organised robes an bowl you may approach a qualified Bhikkhu you trust, bow down and having put the palm over you heart, in kneeling position, ask for going forth three times, that's it, he should lead you to the rest.

Some advices you may also find here: [novices - BMC2](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/thanissaro/bmc2/bmc2.ch24_en.html)

Best success and mudita and feel always welcome to ask questions in a  monastery for going forth and support of it purpose. And it is not wise to approach communities disrespecting and encouraging against the Sangha of monks if wishing to find yourself not under other householders and controlled by them.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*